NuGet Restore keeps coming up with removed package source
I'm currently encountering some problems with nuget / dotnet restore.
Couple of days ago I created myself a NuGet Package on Azure Dev Ops for testing purposes. This Package has been installed at one Project, lets call it ProjectA.
Now the Problem is, when trying to dotnet restore on ProjectB it wanted the Credentials for the Package source, since the credentials window didn't show up (neither hidden or outside VS) I decided to remove the package source completly. I cleared the nuget cache, deleted the obj and bin folder, deleted the nuget config, removed unused reference, cleaned & rebuild the project - the issue still persists.
Now comes the "funny" part, I then decided to load up the test project (ProjectA) and remove the test nuget package there, after this, I can restore ProjectA. But the Error still occurs at ProjectB, ProjectC... which never had the nuget package installed in the first place.
I can't compile/build anything with dotnet since the restore always fails. This is the error msg:
C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\8.0.108\NuGet.targets(156,5): error : Unable to load the service index for source https://p
kgs.dev.azure.com/xxxxx/_packaging/xxxxx/nuget/v3/index.json. [E:\Users\Haku\source\repos\ProjectB\ProjectB\ProjectB.csproj]
C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\8.0.108\NuGet.targets(156,5): error :   Response status code does not indicate success: 401
 (Unauthorized).```



Did you check .csproj references? Or .package files?

Indeed I did, no references were there

the source is probably defined in your user nuget.config file: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/consume-packages/configuring-nuget-behavior  you can also get more information about where nuget.config settings are defined by running dotnet nuget config get --show-path all

Try to remove the package source, https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/consume-packages/install-use-packages-visual-studio#package-sources

As I have written above, I already have checked the nuget.config (and even deleted it) and also removed the package sources

you didn't say WHICH nuget.config file. There can be many. one in the repo, one in your home directory are the most common, but others might apply. The docs I linked explains their multiple locations. As I wrote, run dotnet nuget config get --show-path all. If that doesn't show it, then it's probably coming in via an MSBuild variable, so then you can run dotnet restore -bl, then open msbuild.binlong with https://msbuildlog.com and search for the URL

Solution to the issue was reinstalling the .NET 8 SDK. Apparently it was some weird caching issue since ALL configs etc where cleared.
